# What is the correct formula for the Mann-Whitney U test?

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, notation

I have noticed an inconsistency in the formula for the Mann-Whitney U test. Sites like [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test) often report it as $$U_1={\frac{n_1(n_1+1)}2}-R_1$$ However, the original paper by [Mann and Whitney](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177730491) reports it  as $$U_1=n_1n_2+{\frac{n_1(n_1+1)}2}-R_1$$ What difference does $n_1n_2$ make?

Or are these different tests?

Comment: It's all the same test. Sometimes people shift, scale, or otherwise transform the test statistic. What matters in a statistical test is the P-value as a function of the data. The test statistic is just an intermediate value. Sometimes the convention for a statistic is universal, sometimes less so.

Comment: See  1. [Mann-Whitney U Statistic seems very large - is something wrong?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/252976/mann-whitney-u-statistic-seems-very-large-is-something-wrong)


2. [Why are there two forms for the Mann-Whitney U test statistic?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122985/why-are-there-two-forms-for-the-mann-whitney-u-test-statistic)

3. [Wilcoxon rank sum test in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65844/wilcoxon-rank-sum-test-in-r)

Answer (score 3):

It's the same test, but you're actually reading it wrong. Wikipedia defines $U_1$ as:

$$
U_1 = R_1 - \frac{n_1(n_1+1)}{2}
$$

And, using the same notation, the Mann-Whitney paper defines $U_1$ as:

$$
U_1 = n_1n_2 + \frac{n_2(n_2+1)}{2}-R_2
$$

Note that aside from the $n_1n_2$ piece, the rest of the definition of $U_1$ is actually in terms of $n_2$ and $R_2$ ($m$ and $T$ in the paper). Actually you can do some rearranging to get $U_1$ directly in terms of $U_2$:

$$
U_1 = n_1n_2 - (R_2-\frac{n_2(n_2+1)}{2})
$$

The bracketed term is of course just $U_2$, so:

$$
U_1 = n_1n_2 - U_2
$$

You can see that this is true by considering the fact that the sum of all ranks is just $\frac{(n_1+n_2)(n_1+n_2+1)}{2}$, so:

$$
R_1+R_2=\frac{(n_1+n_2)(n_1+n_2+1)}{2}
$$

Putting $R_1$ and $R_2$ in terms of $U_1$ and $n_1$ and $U_2$ and $n_2$ yields:

$$
U_1+\frac{(n_1)(n_1+1)}{2}+U_1+\frac{(n_2)(n_2+1)}{2}=\frac{(n_1+n_2)(n_1+n_2+1)}{2}
$$

Then you can do some algebra and see the relationship between $U_1$ and $U_2$:

$$U_1=n_1n_2-U_2$$